# How to center vertically RNE Icon?

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I'm using `react-native-elements` `Icon` component and I'm trying to make it smaller, but only the height, not the size. I want to keep the same size, but with a smaller height.

The Problem is that when I change the height of the icon, the icon itself doesn't get up, only cuts the bottom part of the icon.

I want to center the icon.

Here is the icon with no height, it has some weird paddings that even with padding zero, it doesn't go away.
[image: button-normal]

Here is the icon with a smaller height, but the bottom part of the icon is cut off.
[image: button-smaller]

Here is the code I have done so far. Trying to make the `Icon` smaller.
* *only important parts*

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'

<Icon
    name='angle-up'
    type='font-awesome'
    color='blue'
    containerStyle={iconStyles.container}
    iconStyle={iconStyles.icon}
    onPress={() => this.handlePlusValue(time, i)} 
    size={75}
/>

const iconStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    icon: {
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        height: 50,
        textAlign: 'center', 
        width: 100, 
    },
});
```

How can I make the height of the icon smaller, without changing the size of it, but also make the icon in the center?

Comment: can you please provide your code in expo?

Comment: What do you mean by "in expo" ?

Comment: in expo snack https://snack.expo.io/ .

Comment: I don't use expo, and also, why would you want it in expo? What difference would make to solve this problem? You can just put the code I provide and it's the same..